# My program stops when it isn't supposed to ( C)

Tags: c

So this is my code, it's supposed to calculate tolls for an highway, and to stop the "do while" I put a variable "risp" so when the user has finished they write 1, if they want to continue they input 0 but when i test it and i input 0 the code stops anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int kmpercorsi, codice, risp, totcentro, numautocentro;
  float pedaggio, pedaggiomax, mediapedaggiocentro;
  do 
     { 
         printf("Inserisci i km percorsi e il codice di provenienza 0=Nord, 1=Centro, 2=Sud\n");
         scanf("%d%d", &kmpercorsi, &codice);
       if(kmpercorsi <=100)
        {
            if(codice=0 )
            {
                
            pedaggio = (0.15 * kmpercorsi) + 0.01 * kmpercorsi;
            }
            else if (codice = 1)
            {
             pedaggio = (0.125 * kmpercorsi) + 0.01 * kmpercorsi;
             totcentro = totcentro + pedaggio;
             numautocentro++;
            } 
            else 
             {
             pedaggio = (0.1 * kmpercorsi) + 0.01 * kmpercorsi;
             }
         } 
         else 
         {
           
           if (codice = 0) 
            {
               pedaggio = (0.15 * kmpercorsi) + 10 + 0.005 * (kmpercorsi-100);
            }
           else if (codice = 1) 
            {
               pedaggio = (0.125 * kmpercorsi) + 10 + 0.005 * (kmpercorsi-100);
               totcentro = totcentro + pedaggio;
               numautocentro++;
            }
           else 
            {
             pedaggio = (0.1 * kmpercorsi) + 10 + 0.005 * (kmpercorsi-100);  
            }
        }
         if(pedaggio>pedaggiomax) 
        {
          pedaggiomax = pedaggio;
        }
       printf( "Il pedaggio da pagare é:%f\n ", pedaggio);
       printf("Elenco finito? 1=si 0=no\n");
       scanf("%d", &risp);
    } 
    while(risp = 0);
  printf("Il pedaggio più alto è:%f\n ", pedaggiomax);
  mediapedaggiocentro = totcentro/numautocentro;
  printf("La media di tutti i pedaggi delle auto provenienti dal centro é:%f\n ", mediapedaggiocentro);
 
    return 0;
}
```

If I put 0 to continue and 1 to finish and change while to this

```
while(risp = 1);
```

and I input 0 the code doesn't stop and repeats the loop and I can't stop it.

Comment: In `while(risp = 0);`, `risp = 0` is an *assignment*, not a comparison. You probably want `while(risp == 0);`. You have other similar errors, such as `if (codice = 0)`.